# uninitialized constant Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am unable to run my Sinatra application.

I get the following error:

```
application.rb:1:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Sinatra (NameError)
```

here is line 1 of application.rb:

```
class Application < Sinatra::Base
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

I have installed Sinatra as a gem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just installing a gem does not make it automatically loaded; you have to do that manually via `require`. Add `require 'sinatra'` before you do anything Sinatra-related and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Because, it's modular, it makes sense to use:

```
require 'sinatra/base'
```

There's a subtle difference. In most cases, you would really need:

```
require 'sinatra'
```

Comment: Yes that's correct you have to require first